# Comparing two Fonts (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, fonts, equatable

I have two custom `Font` variables using a custom font. The catch is that that are both of the same font class and size.

```
/// Font: Oswald-Regular
/// Size: 16
static var normalText: Font { Font.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: 16) }
    
/// Font: Oswald-Light
/// Size: 16
static var lightText: Font { Font.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: 16) }
```

The issue occurs when I call something like `Font.normalText == Font.lightText`. I am currently getting a result of `True` here. I would like to get a result of `False` from this call so I can apply different letter spacing, capitalization, etc.

How should I go about making sure this equals call returns `False` for two different instances of the same custom font?

Comment: But how you want get false?! You are comparing 2 equal value together. It would be always true. Unless you change size or the name.

Comment: for `normalText == lightText` I get `false` – isn't that what you want?

Comment: AH. I caught a typo in my question. Just updated it.

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are the same, they will always be equaled.

If you need to compare them and get `false`, you could use an `enum`. In the example below the `enum` can be used to compare two different cases and will return `false`; when you want to use the fonts, however, it will require you to specify it by using the property `.font`.

The `enum` is not an extension of `Font`, you will have to use a different name. So, you cannot use the notation `.font(.normalText)` but rather `.font(FontEnum.normalText.font)`.

```
struct FontView: View {
    
    /// Font: Oswald-Regular
    /// Size: 16
    static var normalText: Font { Font.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: 16) }
        
    /// Font: Oswald-Light
    /// Size: 16
    static var lightText: Font { Font.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: 16) }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Text("\(String(FontView.normalText == FontView.lightText))")            // true
                Text("\(String(FontEnum.normalText == FontEnum.lightText))")            // false
                Text("\(String(FontEnum.normalText.font == FontEnum.lightText.font))")  // true
                Text("Using the font")
                    .font(FontEnum.normalText.font)

            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    enum FontEnum {
        case normalText, lightText
        
        var font: Font {
            switch self {
            case .normalText:
                return Font.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: 16)
            case .lightText:
                return Font.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: 16)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is a very solid workaround. I appreciate the response and will give it a shot